# How to save a graphic created by CorePlot to a jpg file

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am using CorePlot to draw different graphs in my application. Then, I would like to save this graph to a jpg file and publish to some social networking site (e.g., Twitter).

I did some documentation reading and understood that the following methods could be useful for me:

- CGBitmapContextCreateImage: creating a CGImage as a copy from a bitmap graphics context (i.e., the view where my graph is situated or the whole screen - have I understood right?)
- CGImageCreateWithImageInRect: I can clip out some part of the image if needed
- [UIImage imageWithCGImage]: converting CGImage to an UIImage object
- UIImageJPEGRepresentation: converting my UIImage object to a jpg NSData object which then I can share to my social network

  1. The first question is: have I understood right the sequence of operations I have to carry out to accomplish my task? I would have tried it out myself, but I've got a problem which leads to the second question:
  2. From where do I get the graphics context info to pass into **CGBitmapContextCreateImage** if I am using CorePlot? Sorry if it's a dumb question, but I am not really at home with graphics contexts.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance! And if I get with all this somewhere I promise to post my code sample here.

Well, thanks to Brad, it was really easy, but as I promissed, I have to post the lines:

```
CPXYGraph *graph=[[CPXYGraph alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];

// setting up the graph
// ...

UIImage *newImage=[graph imageOfLayer];
NSData *newPNG=UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage); // or you can use JPG or PDF

// For test purposes I write the file to the Documents directory, but you can do whatever you want with your new .png file
NSString *filePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/graph.png", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];

if([newPNG writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) 
    NSLog(@"Created new file successfully");
```

Comment: As a side note, have you considered png instead of jpg? It might be better for computer generated graphics like charts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, the CPLayer base class used for all drawing elements in Core Plot has a category method called `-imageOfLayer` that returns a UIImage instance of whatever layer you call it on.  See the `CPPlatformSpecificCategories.h` and `CPPlatformSpecificCategories.m` files in the framework if you want to see how this is accomplished.

Simply use `-imageOfLayer` on your CPGraph instance and then use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` to create the JPEG version of that image.  You can then upload that image using the normal means.

Likewise, there is a `-dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer` method that returns an NSData instance containing a PDF representation of the layer and its sublayers.

Comment: HI.. IS this Possible Whole Graph Image.. i got only 320 X 460 ..Visiable Graph Image.. i want Full Graph Image..? how can i Get it...?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know much about CorePlot.  But I assume CorePlot provides a view that renders a graph to itself.  If CorePlot doesn't provide a mechanism to get a `UIImage` of the graph, then you can probably trick CorePlot into drawing into your own Bitmap Graphics Context, from which you can create an image object to save.

Here's the basic approach:

1) create a bitmap graphics context using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`.  This will also make the context the "current" context.  You could also use `CGBitmapContextCreate()` but then you'd also have to use `UIGraphicsPushContext()` to make it current.

2) call the CorePlot view's `drawRect:` method.

3) get the image from the graphics context using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`

4) clean up with `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`

5) get your Jpeg bits into a `NSData` object using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`.

6) save/upload your jpeg using `NSData` methods (or other..)