# Export Core-Plot to CSV / Excel - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, csv, core-plot

I've been asked to extend an app I've built to include the ability to export a graph, which is created using Core-Plot, for use in Excel.

Is there currently anyway to do this? Or is the 'only' way to export the data for the graph as a CSV file which the user then turns into the graph?

My current idea was to get the user to email the CSV file using the iPad/iPhone in built mail API..

Cheers.

Comment: Is exporting as a PDF acceptable? I think that's about as close as you're going to get to being able to export the visible portion of a graph.

Comment: @Brad I guess if it's the only to go it will be! How would I go about doing that..?

Comment: See my answer here for how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4228003/19679